# @kubernetes/client-node: How to connect to a remote server using its loadFromOptions?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I'm trying to connect to a remote server from Node.js via `"@kubenetes/client-node"` as

```js
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node')
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig()
const cluster = {name: 'default', server: 'https://my-server.com'}
const user = {name: 'xxx', password: 'yyy'}
const context = {name: 'default', user: user.name, cluster: cluster.name}
kc.loadFromOptions({ clusters: [cluster], users: [user], contexts: [context], currentContext: context.name })
const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api)
k8sApi.listPodForAllNamespaces().then(r => {
    console.log(r.body)
})
```

I don't see any errors but I only get

```json
V1PodList {
    apiVersion: undefined,
    items: undefined,
    kind: undefined,
    metadata: undefined
}
```

What did I miss? Using the same parameters, I was able to SSH to the server and get pods using `kubectl` directly.